# The image resizes after entering several letters

Tags: html, css

In short, if I enter many letters, the image resizes automatically and no longer has the correct shape. I would like the image to remain the same. For example, this code is for accounts, If someone has a longer name than they can carry the sidebar at the end of the sidebar will appear `...` The problem is that if those `...` appear, the image is resized as well.

If I try to put position: absolute the text goes over the image

```css
.gh-rec-acc {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 107.5%;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #201f24;
  background-color: var(--theme);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.gh-rec-acc:hover {
  background-color: #2e2d33;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
.gh-rec-sideimg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.gh-rec-sidename {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 6px 13px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<section class="gh-rec-acc">
    <img class="gh-rec-sideimg" src="/img/test.png" alt="">
    <div class="gh-rec-sidename">Alexander</div>
</section>
```

EDIT: This is how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on the size of the images you can do something like this

```
.gh-rec-sideimg {
    min-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `img` to `position: absolute` and add the width of the image as the `margin-left` for the element that holds the user's name.

```css
.gh-rec-acc {
  border: 1px solid #201f24;
  background-color: var(--theme);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px 0 50px 0;
}

.gh-rec-sideimg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.gh-rec-sidename {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 13px 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<section class="gh-rec-acc">
  <img class="gh-rec-sideimg" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1838/1*MI686k5sDQrISBM6L8pf5A.jpeg" alt="">
  <div class="gh-rec-sidename">Alexander</div>
</section>

<section class="gh-rec-acc">
  <img class="gh-rec-sideimg" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1838/1*MI686k5sDQrISBM6L8pf5A.jpeg" alt="">
  <div class="gh-rec-sidename">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
</section>
```